# Ubuntu, её процессы

Tags: c, ubuntu, процесс

Такая проблема: Процесс 1 открывает файл и порождает потомков 2 и 3. Потомки после сигнала от предка пишут в файл по N байт, посылают сигналы процессу 1 и завершают работу. После этого процесс 1 считывает данные из файла и выводит на экран. Нужно написать на языке С, чтобы Терминал Ubuntu смог обработать. Процессы пишут в файл данные, но криво. Понимаю, что всё это может быть в корне неправильно, но это максимум, что я смог сделать.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PERMS 0666
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
char ch2 = '0';
char ch3 = '1';
int n = 0;
struct stat filest;
struct stat temp2;
struct stat temp3;
int proc1, proc2, proc3, st, fd;
printf("Process 1, PID %d\n", proc1 = getpid());
n = (int)atoi(argv[2]);
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
fstat(fd, &filest);
temp2 = filest;
temp3 = filest;
if ( (proc2 = fork()) == 0 )
{
    printf("Process 2, PID %d\n", proc2 = getpid());
    while( (int)temp2.st_mtime == (int)filest.st_mtime && 
(int)temp2.st_atime == (int)filest.st_atime )
    fstat(fd, &filest);
    printf("Process 2 is writing\n");
    while( n != 0)
    {
        n--;
        write(fd, &ch2, 1);
    }
    kill(proc2,SIGKILL); //после записи убиваю второй процесс
}
if ( (proc3 = fork()) == 0 )
{
    printf("Process 3, PID %d\n", proc3 = getpid());
    while( (int)temp3.st_mtime == (int)filest.st_mtime && 
(int)temp3.st_atime == (int)filest.st_atime )
    fstat(fd, &filest);
    printf("Process 3 is writing\n");
    while( n != 0)
    {
        n--;
        write(fd, &ch3, 1);
    }
    kill(proc3,SIGKILL); //после записи убиваю третий процесс
}
else
{
    printf("Process 1 is writing\n");
    while( n != 0)
    {
        n--;
        write(fd, &ch3, 1);
    }
    read(fd, &ch3, 1);
    close(fd);
}
wait(&st);
FILE* f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
n = (int)atoi(argv[2]);
char res[n]; //строка с результатом
if(n>0)
{
    fgets(res, n*8, (FILE*)f1); //считываю определенное кол-во байт)
    printf("%s",res);
}
fclose(f1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: интересно, а зачем вы убиваете процессы kill ? процесс может спокойно завершаться exit(). И что значит "криво пишут", ваша программа рассчитана на запись символов в случайном порядке, если это и требуется, то все нормально они пишут. кроме того wait ожидает завершения одного любого из потомков, значит когда вы начинаете читать возможно еще не все что то записали. Ну а какое отношение к вопросу имеет "терминал ubuntu" (и чем он отличается от других терминалов), вообще не ясно. терминал выдает ровным счетом то, что вы на него пишите.

Comment: хорошо, а как тогда в данной ситуации можно ожидать завершения этих двух процессов? Что нужно в коде поменять?
P.S. Понимаю Ваше недовольство, возмущение, но я в этом новенький

Comment: `while (wait(&st) > 0);` но на порядок записи это ни как не скажется. И кроме того, при убийстве процесса SIGKILL, не закрывая файла, данные вполне могут и не записаться.